# How can I get all records from the database table where the counterparty_id is equal to the received value from the session with the last time stamp?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

There are two tables with names "table_A" and "table_B".

table_A contains records of documents.
table_B constains records of transactions.

When creating a new document, a new record is created in table_A and table_B.

```
$this->arData = $this->Transaction->where( 'sender' , '=' , session('contragent_id') )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
```

And I get the following data:

[data screen img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7AJf.png)

As you can see, a single document can have several transactions (1), (2). And of these transactions, I only need one, with the last timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the array into a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections), then order it by the `created_at`, finally get the first result of the sorted array.

```
collect($this->artData)->orderBy('created_at', 'Desc')->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access the `Transaction` property you would actually retrive the models from the database, before you do so you can further narrow down your query with additional constraints by calling the relationship as a function instead of a property.

This should do the trick:

```php
$this->arData = $this->Transaction()->where('sender', '=', session('contragent_id'))->orderByDesc('created_at')->first();
```

Note that with `->first()` method call at the end you get a single model instance, then you can extract whatever value you will need to save in `$this->arData`, as you didn't specify which value it should contain.